# What is the purpose of Dynamics CRM Child execution pipeline and when they get fired or executed?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

i know dynamics crm event execution pipeline either Parent or Child but i want to know what is the purpose of the child pipeline and when the child pipeline get fired. Could you give me examples that clarify this issue? and in case of they are deprecated, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Anything in particular trigger this question?

Comment: i don't understand you

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was an error or issue that caused you to ask about alternates to the Child execution pipeline.

Comment: Hi Dary1, I just want to understand the event execution pipeline in dynamics crm as i built similar system

Answer (score 1):

Child pipelines were deprecated in CRM 2011 so unless you're working with CRM 4.0 you don't need to concern yourself with them.

For context however, [this blog](http://crmscape.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/ms-crm-40-plug-in-stages-pipelines-and.html) post provides all the information you need on the differences.